# How to include a module that extends classmethods and correctly reference class var

Tags: ruby, include, extend

My expectations are in the comments.

```
require 'logger'

module Logging
  attr_accessor :logger

  def logger
    return @logger if @logger # allow items to have own loggers
    @@logger ||= Logger.new(STDERR)
    puts "Instance Class REF ID#{@@logger.__id__}"
    puts "Class ID #{self.class.logger.__id__}"
    @@logger
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def logger= logger
      @logger = logger
    end

    def logger
      @logger ||= Logger.new(STDERR)
      puts "Class Instance REF ID #{@logger.__id__}"
      @logger
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

class Test

  include Logging

  def wow
    logger.info 'wow'
  end
end

t = Test.new

# should be the same
puts "Loggers are #{t.logger.__id__ == Test.logger.__id__ ? '' : 'not '}the same"

Test.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')

# should still be the same
puts "Loggers are #{t.logger.__id__ == Test.logger.__id__ ? '' : 'not '}the same"

lg = Test.logger.__id__
t.logger =  Logger.new(STDERR)

# class logger should be same
puts "Class Logger is #{Test.logger.__id__ == lg ? 'still the' : 'not'} same"

# class and instance logger should be different
puts "Loggers are #{t.logger.__id__ == Test.logger.__id__ ? '' : 'not '}the same"
```

When executed:

```
➜  sandbox  irb
1.9.3-p392 :001 > load 'test_l.rb'
Instance Class REF ID70203753590760
Class Instance REF ID 70203753590500
Class ID 70203753590500
Class Instance REF ID 70203753590500

Loggers are not the same  # I expected to be same... :(

Instance Class REF ID70203753590760
Class Instance REF ID 70203753590000
Class ID 70203753590000
Class Instance REF ID 70203753590000

Loggers are not the same  # I expected to be same... :(

Class Instance REF ID 70203753590000
Class Instance REF ID 70203753590000

Class Logger is still the same

Class Instance REF ID 70203753590000

Loggers are not the same
```

Comment: please consider editing the title to make it useful.

Comment: Your title needs to reflect the question you are asking. As is, it's worthless.

Comment: Learn to use better/more-descriptive names for your variables and methods. As is, YOU will have a hard time keeping it straight in your head six months from now. Don't reuse the same name for instance and class variables AND methods at the main and class levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've deliberately forgotten how to use `@@` variables because they are so confusing and rarely needed.

Instead, consider only using instance variables, but delegate up to the class level if needed:

```
module Logging
  attr_writer :logger

  def logger
    defined?(@logger) ? @logger : self.class.logger
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def logger=(logger)
      @logger = logger
    end

    def logger
      @logger ||= Logger.new(STDERR)
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

class Test
  include Logging

  # ...
end
```